# ionic2 apply ngx-translate for menu items

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate for multi language support and it is working fine. but i want to apply for menu items also. How do i achieve this.

I have 3 menu items, i want to change the language for every title.

### ts file

```
appPages: PageObj[] = [
    { title: 'Profile', component: ProfilePage, icon: 'person' },
    { title: 'My Account', component: MyaccountPage, index: 1, icon: 'cash' },    
    { title: 'FAQ', component: FaqPage, index: 3, icon: 'chatbubbles' }    
  ];
```

### HTML

```
 <button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let p of appPages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon item-left [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
     {{p.title}}
 </button>
```

### And my module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {AppComponent} from './app';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should create json file for difference languages in assets folder such as **en.json, fr.json, kh.json**.

[image]

**en.json:**

```
{
  // Your content...,
  "PROFILE": "Profile",
  "MY_ACCOUNT": "My Account",
  "FAQ": "FAQ"
}
```

And change title of PageObj as below:

```
appPages: PageObj[] = [
    { title: 'PROFILE', component: ProfilePage, icon: 'person' },
    { title: 'MY_ACCOUNT', component: MyaccountPage, index: 1, icon: 'cash' },    
    { title: 'FAQ', component: FaqPage, index: 3, icon: 'chatbubbles' }    
  ];
```

And correct your app.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {AppComponent} from './app';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [Http]
            }
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your view (***.html**), you need to use **translate pipe**:

```
<button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let p of appPages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon item-left [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
     {{ p.title | translate }}
 </button>
```

if you want to set default or use language:

```
// this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
translate.setDefaultLang('en');

// the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
translate.use('en');
```

[You can read The internationalization (i18n) library for Angular 2+ with this url : http://www.ngx-translate.com](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

Hope this could help ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `title` property from each side menu item, to be the translation key, like this:

```
// Language file
// en.json
{
  // Your content...,
  "PROFILE": "Profile",
  "MY_ACCOUNT": "My Account",
  "FAQ": "FAQ"
}
```

And in your `.ts` file:

```
appPages: PageObj[] = [
    { title: 'PROFILE', component: ProfilePage, icon: 'person' },
    { title: 'MY_ACCOUNT', component: MyaccountPage, index: 1, icon: 'cash' },    
    { title: 'FAQ', component: FaqPage, index: 3, icon: 'chatbubbles' }    
  ];
```

Then in the view, just add the `translate` pipe to each menu item:

```
<button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let p of appPages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon item-left [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
     {{ p.title | translate }}
 </button>
```

Comment: thanks sebaferreras..its working fine. Earlier i used events to change the language settings. u saved me writing lot of code.

Comment: Glad to help! :)