# Ionic - Alert Strings Localization

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, localization, internationalization, ionic3

I have multiple areas in the code (across multiple pages) that I wish to use the different languages. Instead of writing each function with an if-else condition, I want to have a separate file with all strings in EN and AR so that I can import based on what is needed. I am already using ngx-translate for the views translation (button, labels, etc.), but I want to figure out how to do the same or something similar for the actual typescript classes.

I looked at angular-translate and didn't understand how to use it.

E.g.

```
let alert = self.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Username Taken',
                    subTitle: 'The username you entered is already registered.',
                    buttons: ['Retry']
                  });
                  alert.present();
```

I will check to see which language option was selected by user (based on Events) and then want to have title, subtitle and buttons in English or Arabic or whatever other language I support.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem with ionic 4 and ngx-translate. this is how I solve it.
this is my ts file code

```
async presentAlert() {
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: this.translate.instant('Alert'),
  subHeader: this.translate.instant('empty_fields'),
  message: this.translate.instant('enter_fields'),
  buttons: [this.translate.instant('ok')]
});

await alert.present();
```

}

this is my JSON file

```
    {
"Alert": "Alert",
    "empty_fields": "Empty Fields",
    "enter_fields": "Enter Required Fields!!",
    "ok": "OK",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below code in ionic3

```js
1st import translateService in ts
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

2nd in app.module.ts add below:
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
imports: [
    TranslateModule
  ]


showAlert(){
    this.translate.get(['Cancel','Ok']).subscribe(res => {
    //in res we will get translated data and fetch via key
    console.log(res);
  });
 }
```

In above code ['Cancel','Ok'] are JSON key

Answer (score -1):

He, the solution is simple, to make translation from the controller (.ts) is different from doing it from the view (.html). To do it from the controller follow the following steps:

1- Import the translation module.
2- Inject the translation object in the constructor of the page you want to use it.
3- Use the injected object to make the translation.

In code:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

....

constructor (public translate: TranslateService){
}

showMessage(){
 let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
  message: msg,
  duration: 4500
});
toast.present();    
}

//Take a look to this funcion this.translate.instant("the key");
callShowMessage(){   

this.showMessage(this.translate.instant("toast.message.wrongauth"));
}
```

Regards,

Comment: This is not very clear ....I imported the TranslateService class, and in the alert subtitle I tried to use String(this.translate.get("ALERT_USERNAME_TAKEN") ) but it didn't work.

Comment: Try the way I explain above, the get method, the function "get" return an Observable and "instant" is synchronous, personally I prefer instant. Check more in the [doc](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) of ngx-translate core.

Comment: pls read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706135/ionic2-apply-ngx-translate-for-menu-items